# Java - Sort arrays by first array index?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing

I'm new to java (& not too great at explaining but I'll do my best) and at a point in my assignment where I've to sort other arrays based on array 1s sorting. 
Say if we have three 2d arrays and sort it a-z based upon the array of Names:

```
 String[][]Names = { {"Bob", "James", "Mary", "Felix"}, {"Calvin", "Kurt", "Chris", "Ethan" } };
 int[][]Age = { {19, 20, 30, 33} , {20, 31, 51, 43} };
 Double[][]Hours_Worked = { {19.5, 20.4, 39.9, 25.2} , {5.5, 10.9, 15.2, 20.9} };
```

Then once it's sorted, the other arrays follow the values around like so in the output :

```
Bob : 19 : 19.5
Calvin : 20 : 5.5
Chris : 31 : 10.9
```

What must I do to achieve this?.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Sort the first array. After that iterate it and assign all values from the other ones. Should be relatively easy as you have all indices from iterating the first array and can just put them into the others. Of course you need some kind of additional data structure to create the linkings. For example a `PersonData` class. and then an `List<PersonData>`.

Comment: Please stick to **naming conventions**. Variable names start with a lower case character and classes with uppercase. Also you probably wanted to use `double` instead of `Double` (it is a difference).

Comment: Or do you want to also change the order on the other arrays? In that case I recommend temporarily moving **everything** into containers like said `List<PersonData>`. Then sort this list based on the names. After that re-create the arrays from it, if you really need arrays.

Comment: @Zabuza thanks for your recommendations and yeah what I'm trying to do is change the order of the other arrays after sorting the 1st one.  So basically all I need to do is add the other arrays into a temporarily list and just re-order the list?

Comment: I'm not looking for the code but rather an explanation on how to get it get done so I can head off and do it.

Comment: @ErikWeisz - One method to do this without having to combine the arrays into a common container is to create an array of indices 0 to n-1, in this case 0 to 3. Then sort the array of indices according to the names (typically using a lambda compare function). Then sort the string arrays according to the now sorted array of indices. This can be done in place following the logic in the C function in this [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775994/reorder-array-according-to-given-index/46776144#46776144) .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most readable way I could imagine would be to first **parse** the data and create **container classes** which represent the correlation between the data items, `PersonData`. After that **collect it** in some way that the structure is remained, `List<List<PersonData>>`. Then you may **sort** this based on whatever you like. Afterwards **extract** the information again if you really need those separate arrays.

First the **container class**:

```
public class PersonData {
    private String mName;
    private int mAge;
    private double mHoursWorked;

    public PersonData(String name, int age, double hoursWorked) {
        this.mName = name;
        this.mAge = age;
        this.mHoursWorked = hoursWorked
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.mName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.mAge;
    }

    public double getHoursWorked() {
        return this.mHoursWorked;
    }
}
```

Now the **parsing and collecting**:

```
String[][] nameData = ...
int[][] ageData = ....
double[][] hoursWorkedData = ...

List<List<PersonData>> data = new ArrayList<>();
for (int outer = 0; outer < nameData.length; outer++) {
    // Create a new group
    List<PersonData> group = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int inner = 0; inner < nameData[outer].length; inner++) {
        // Process this person
        String name = nameData[outer][inner];
        int age = ageData[outer][inner];
        double hoursWoked = hoursWorkedData[outer][inner];

        group.add(new PersonData(name, age, hoursWorked);
    }

    // Add that group
    data.add(group);
}
```

Next the **sorting**, assuming the groups itself are not getting sorted:

```
data.forEach(group -> {
    Collections.sort(group, Comparator.comparing(PersonData::getName));
});
```

Or if you let `PersonData` implement `Comparable` it's just:

```
data.forEach(Collections::sort);
```

After that **extract** the information again and re-create the arrays:

```
String[][] sortedNameData = data.stream()  // Stream<List<PersonData>>
    .map(group -> group.stream()           // sub Stream<PersonData>
        .map(PersonData::getName)          // sub Stream<String>
        .toArray(String[]::new))           // Stream<String[]>
    .toArray(String[][]::new)              // String[][]

int[][] sortedAgeData = data.stream()
    .map(group -> group.stream()
        .map(PersonData::getAge)
        .toArray(int[]::new))
    .toArray(int[][]::new)

double[][] sortedHoursWorkedData = data.stream()
    .map(group -> group.stream()
        .map(PersonData::getHoursWorked)
        .toArray(double[]::new))
    .toArray(double[][]::new)
```

Or you directly work with your new structure

```
List<List<PersonData>>
```

where everything is nicely grouped together by the container class.