# Reorder an Array according to given index in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-api-3

```
let waypointOrder = [1,0,2,3]
var waypoints = ["sydny", "wynard", "surry hills", "Town hall"]
```

I want the `waypoints` to be sorted like this:

```
["Wynard", "sydny", "surry hills", "Town hall"]
```

Explanation: since `waypointOrder[0] = 1` then `orderedWaypoints[0] = waypoints[1]`, if this makes sense...

Well, Google distance API response returning my `waypoint_order`.
I want to reorder my waypoint according to google distance response.

I shall be very thankful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775994/reorder-array-according-to-given-index

Comment: Could you please format, grammar check and spell check this question? It's a mess.

Comment: i hope now it should be fine.

Comment: That's much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` function on the ordering array and use it's returned value to return the value at it's index in the array you want sorted.

```
let waypointOrdering = [1,0,2,3]
var waypoints = ["sydny","wynard","surry hills","Town hall"]
let orderedWaypoints = waypointOrdering.map { waypoints[$0] }
```

output:

```
["wynard", "sydny", "surry hills", "Town hall"]
```

Comment: I think you got the two mixed up

Comment: No, the first array with the ordering is iterated through and each value is used as an index of the array to be sorted.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I got it mixed up, after all :)

Comment: I'm going to edit your answer to use the new terminology I suggested, to make it clearer, if that's alright with you